# What are these ? ه҈҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉

Tags: string, encoding, character

These "characters" seem interesting. What are they?I would like to know more technical information about them. Thanks! 
    ه҈҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉ ه҈҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉ ه҈҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉

Comment: [C̨̦̺̩̲̥͉̭͚̜̻̝̣̼͙̮̯̪o̴̡͇̘͎̞̲͇̦̲͞͡m̸̩̺̝̣̹̱͚̬̥̫̳̼̞̘̯͘ͅẹ͇̺̜́̕͢ - What kind of string is this?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46184958/995714)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's just a mass of [combining marks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_mark). That alone is like 170 Combining Marks. You can do all sorts of [weird rendering effects](http://jsfiddle.net/YEJfr/2/) just by using a ton of combining marks together. But in this case just [U+0489 COMBINING CYRILLIC MILLIONS SIGN](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/489/index.htm) is used.

Combining marks are not stand alone characters by themselves, but modify the previous base letter. For example `a`, a combining diaeresis `¨` renders as `ä` instead of `a¨`. Put more combining marks in there, and they all have to somehow render with the base character `a`, causing interesting rendering effect.

Code in the jsfiddle (SO didn't allow me to post otherwise):

```
var l = 1000;

var str = ":"

while(l--) {
    str += String.fromCharCode(0x300 + Math.floor((Math.random() * 0x20)))
}

document.write(str);
```

Answer (score 3):

Those are [unicode](http://www.unicode.org/standard/WhatIsUnicode.html) characters that belong to another character set/language (in this case, Cyrillic).  This information can be seen (on Windows) by using the Character Map tool, which is found in the Programs -> Accessories folder of the Start Menu.

Comment: These are showing up to me as the Cyrillic Hundred-Thousands sign (U+0488).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrillic_numerals, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_Cyrillic_Hundred_Thousands

Comment: ҈ this is the Cyrillic hundred thousands sign, which is not that surprising, it's more/less just like other weird looking symbols in other fonts. What I would like to know more about is the more interesting stuff hanging below and to the left; like technically how are they being rendered? They can show in anywhere I paste them and even overlap other UI objects.