# C̨̦̺̩̲̥͉̭͚̜̻̝̣̼͙̮̯̪o̴̡͇̘͎̞̲͇̦̲͞͡m̸̩̺̝̣̹̱͚̬̥̫̳̼̞̘̯͘ͅẹ͇̺̜́̕͢ - What kind of string is this?

Tags: unicode, zalgo

**H̸̷͓̳̳̯̟͕̟͍͍̣͡ḛ̢̦̰̺̮̝͖͖̘̪͉͘͡ ̠̦͕̤̪̝̥̰̠̫̖̣͙̬͘ͅC̨̦̺̩̲̥͉̭͚̜̻̝̣̼͙̮̯̪o̴̡͇̘͎̞̲͇̦̲͞͡m̸̩̺̝̣̹̱͚̬̥̫̳̼̞̘̯͘ͅẹ͇̺̜́̕͢s̶̙̟̱̥̮̯̰̦͓͇͖͖̝͘͘͞**

.

I found this string in [Cookie Clicker](http://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/). It seems it is made of 8 wired big characters which are then made of many unicode characters connected together.

What kind of characters are those, what's their purpose and is there a way to type them?

Comment: Why not? This looks like it to me.

Comment: @Zissouu: ["The "H̸̷͓̳̳̯̟͕̟͍͍̣͡ḛ̢̦̰̺̮̝͖͖̘̪͉͘͡ ̠̦͕̤̪̝̥̰̠̫̖̣͙̬͘ͅC̨̦̺̩̲̥͉̭͚̜̻̝̣̼͙̮̯̪o̴̡͇̘͎̞̲͇̦̲͞͡m̸̩̺̝̣̹̱͚̬̥̫̳̼̞̘̯͘ͅẹ͇̺̜́̕͢s̶̙̟̱̥̮̯̰̦͓͇͖͖̝͘͘͞" achievement is a reference to Zalgo."](http://cookieclicker.wikia.com/wiki/Achievement)

Comment: @genpfault: Yes, that's it. Unfortunately, it is impossible to search for it...

Comment: In the linked question you will find a way to do so :)

Comment: Great now I'm stuck playing cookie clicker again